# How to write a "Not In" SQL query in LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How would I translate the following SQL query in to a comparable LINQ query?

```
select * from Dept 
where Id not in (
    Select Id 
    from Employee 
    where Salary > 100);
```

Comment: Also, LinqPad is a handy tool to aid in writing and testing Linq queries

Comment: in this case you could also use logical negation: where Salary <=100

Comment: @Chad..ya will try it seems useful
@CrazyJugglerDrummer well i am trying to do something else little more complex...ya but in this case it would :)...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var result = from d in Dept
             let expensiveEmployeeIds = (from e in Employee.Employees
                                       where e.Salary > 100
                                       select e.Id)
             where !expensiveEmployeeIds.Contains(d.Id)
             select d;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var lowPaidEmps = from d in db.Dept 
                  join e in db.Employees on d.Id equals e.Id 
                  where e.Salary <= 100
                  select d;
```

Comment: That's not logically equivalent.  Imagine a department with no employees (original query returns it, this query does not).

Comment: I'm glad you got what you're looking for.